# Merger two similar collections

Tags: laravel

What's the way to merge two collections with identique items?

```
        $id =  1;

        $user = User::find($id);

        $projectsAsMember = $user->projectsAsMember;

        $projectsAsAdmin = $user->projectsAsAdmin;
```

I'm working in Laravel

Comment: what have you attempted so far? there are lots of methods on Collection to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the working solution:

```
        $collection = collect();
        $collection = $collection->merge($projectsAsAdmin);
        $collection = $collection->merge($projectsAsMember);
        $collection = $collection->unique('id');
        $collection = $collection->sortBy('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$projectsAsMember->merge($projectsAsAdmin)->unique()
```

That way, you will merge those 2 collection and get only unique object or value.

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns only the items from `$projectsAsMember`